# create a page which contain a flash can be add text dynamiclly

Tags: html, flash, fullscreen

I have to create a web page which can be set to full screen(I mean the real full screen,not like press the F11),in the full screen there should be some words displaying.

Take the http://stackoverflow.com for example:

Normally,it show its contents(the questions),but someday,maybe a VIP come to visit the page,so we want to replace the whole page with a welcome screen.

Of course we can replace the https://stackoverflow.com/index.html (suppose it is the index page) with the welcome text(welcome xxx to our site...) in the server side.

However this is not convenient,and the text can not be full screened.

So I thought the flash,I can add a controller button at the page,when required,I click this button,and set the welcome words,then a flash will start to play with the sepcified words in a full screen model. It would be better if the flash can show the text with a Animation.

I have never did the flash development,so I want to know if this is possible?

BTW,can all the clients change to flash with juse one click?

I mean I click the controller button,then all the client who is visit this page should see the contents replaced by the flash at the same time.

I am not sure if you guys know what I am meaning. If not,I can update more details.

I am really Anxious, Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're starting from scratch with Flash, I made a quick example of what I *think* you want to do. http://clearmpls.com/temp/fullscreen/ - the source files that I made this example with can be grabbed from here: http://clearmpls.com/temp/xml-loading-fullscreen-thing.zip

I used the Flash IDE to create this. You can grab a 60-day trial from Adobe's site here: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash

This example shows examples of these functions:
- it loads an XML file with text data
- displays that data in a textfield on the stage
- gives you a button where you can toggle back and forth between fullscreen and regular
- resizes the stage and textfield based on what you have written in your XML file

Comment: Thanks,this is just what I need!!! Except that the toggle button can be hidden when full screen. But the example is enough for me !!! However I found that if I set the text in the data.xml with chinese word,the flash can not display them normally. BTW,if I understand it right,the xx.as will be complied to xx.swf,so all everything in the flash are build in the xx.as,so I want to know if we can use a existed flash? Take your example for example,under the text is a blank flash,can it be changed to another flash?

Comment: BWT,what's the tool you used to create the falsh? I use the macromedia flash8,but can not open the xx.fla.

Comment: Hi, I created it in Flash CS5 and saved the file down to Flash CS4. It's built in actionscript 3, so you need to use Flash CS4 or higher to open, edit, or export the swf. You can certainly use this as the basis for your project. The code is in a layer on the timeline and not in an external .as file. It's usually a bit simpler to learn Flash that way, then once you're comfortable with the concepts that Flash uses, then move onto using external .as files.

Comment: And for Chinese characters, you can type those into the XML file, but you will have to embed the correct font for those characters. It works well.

Comment: Thanks,I do not know how to express my appreciation... :)  And What do you mean about embeding the correct font for the characters? Modify the flash?

Comment: Yes, when you open the .fla, click on the textfield, then go to the 'Properties' panel and choose your font, click "embed" and it will bring up a panel that lets you choose which characters to embed for that textfield.

Comment: THank you very much. I got it :). And I try to set the text through the textfield of input type,then show it. :)

Comment: the problem then becomes, then everyone will have access to change your text (granted, it will only be on their computer since you're not POST'ing your textfield content to a database and retrieving it on the live site).

Comment: Yes,after Discussion we think the grant is not necessary. Now my problem is how to make the text move. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232961/how-to-make-the-textfield-in-falsh-move  .Of course,I will try to find some docs myself.  But if you can spare some time to have a check,I will be appreciate,this is the first time I build a flash,and use the actionscript. :)

Comment: Check out Greensock's TweenLite or TweenMax classes - that will make animation easy: http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/