# How can I make the text in a TextField scroll? (like marquee in HTML)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have made a flash project which provides a UI for the user to input some text. The user can change the color, size, style of the text, and now I want the text move like a marquee in HTML.

I have upload my [.fla](http://www.box.net/shared/tk7k6ug2m4), would someone be able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try some of the code given here:

http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/408

Comment: Thanks,I will have a try. And thanks for your reediting my post. :) I am not good at English. :)

Comment: Not a problem, hope that helped you out!

Comment: Thanks @FrenzyLi, I removed the broken link